# Excel 2013 link references to function cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

in A1 i have a hyperlink ../something/something[fileLink.xlsx]

in B1 i have =INDEX('../something/something[fileLink.xlsx]Sheat'!$B$49:$G$207

The B1 field does work fine, however i would like to simplify it something like this.

=INDEX('[A1]Sheat'!$B$49:$G$207

is it possible to extract the A1 hyperlink into B1 function somehow.

Note that it is excel 2013

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

`=INDEX(INDIRECT("'" & A1 & "Sheat'!$B$49:$G$207") ... )`

Comment: Good answer. This is one of those things you 'just need to know' because I don't even know how you'd find it by searching.

Comment: It seems like its the right direction. However when i do this, the value just says #ref

Comment: @RonnieDamsgaardJensen: please share your exact formula, so I can have a look at it. Also please try to evaluate your formula (formulas tab - evaluate) to see where it fails.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I have now read about INDIRECT, and found out that the link in this case is a external workbook have to be open to work. So in my case i think this can not solve it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász 

=INDEX(PROFEXHyperlinkAddress(I11)WBS'!$B$49:$G$207; MATCH(1; ('\\nmea.abb.com\dk\bau active\PAPG\PAPG kunder\Albertslund Varmeværk\Service aftaler\432S19019\03_Fullcost\[432S19019 Servicetemplate Full Cost_2019_001v1.xlsm]WBS'!$B$49:$B$207=O3)*('\\nmea.abb.com\dk\bau active\PAPG\PAPG kunder\Albertslund Varmeværk\Service aftaler\432S19019\03_Fullcost\[432S19019 Servicetemplate Full Cost_2019_001v1.xlsm]WBS'!$C$49:$C$207=O4); 0); 6)